# Where is this knock-off LEGO brick from?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

These are some of the non-LEGO pieces I had in my LEGO collection when I was a child, and I was told they were old LEGO, but any site on the history of LEGO completely failed to show anything like this, so they have to be knock-offs.

[image]

They are likely made in the 60's but it could be earlier. It's compatible with LEGO, except that the studs are higher, so you can't put a thin brick on top of them. The plastic is softer and just slightly translucent. I like their solution for the underside, very neat, and a clever attempt to pass by the LEGO design patents. I don't know the manufacturer, and would appreciate any information.

Comment: My eagle-eye stepdad noticed there was writing between the studs. Turns out they are dutch and called "MONTINI".

Comment: http://www.architoys.net/toys/toypages/montini.html

Comment: I am from Indonesia, I remember having these bricks when I was like 5-6 years old. That was way back in 1970. I had enough of these plastic bricks to build a house, complete with "glass" door and "glass" windows. The plastic was not shiny like Lego pieces. My sister and I had quite a lot of fun with these Montini bricks. Our mother, who always complained there was "too much stuff" in the house, gave our Montini set away once we outgrew it.

Comment: I grew up in South Africa and Montini was a huge hit long before I ever heard of Lego. I assumed Lego was the knock-off of Montini blocks. Montini had lots of different bases, bricks, colors, windows, doors, wheels, etc.

Comment: Bought mixed batch off eBay, Lego,  Duplo & other, which = Montini, can only join Lego to 1/2 the positions under if not using hollow stud Lego such as windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have pointed out, these are Montini building blocks.

[image]

[image]

Montini building blocks were produced by Berco Lux in Tiel, The Netherlands between 1960-1969. The plastic is much softer and the colors are a little different.

In 1969 production was stopped because of the Lego patent.

[Montini history and the conflict with Lego](https://bambinomonti.blogspot.com/2020/04/montini-en-het-conflict-met-lego.html) ( in Dutch)